# "Test Finished" handler in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

How to add a Test-Finished handler to a jasmine test?

I need it to deallocate resources consumed by the test.

I'm using the very latest version of [jasmine 2.3.1](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/releases/tag/v2.3.1) with Node JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **afterAll** block for this purpose.

from [documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html) : `afterAll function is called after all specs finish...`

```
describe("afterAll function", function() {

  afterAll(function() {
    //release resources here after all the test suits have finished running
  });

});
```